# Modular Cubic Formula

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, cubics

What would be the process of solving a modular cubic equation? Eg.
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\pmod n$$
In the case that I was given, $d$ is a (*very*) large number, so rational root theorem isn't a viable option. I have two of these cubic equations and I have to find an $x$ value  that satisfies both of them, so is there any method to solving this problem? If it means anything, the cubic I'm dealing with is factorable to a form of $(ax+b)^3$

Comment: Do your two equations have the same $n$?  Are the $a$'s coprime to $n$?  Can you get a quadratic from a linear combination of the two equations?

Comment: If $d$ is very large and $n$ is not very large, then $d$ reduces to something that is not very large.  So the question of how big $n$ is, is of more interest than the statement about $d$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy $n$ and $d$ are roughly the same size, $n$ being a bit bigger.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  In both equations $n$ is the same, however I'll check if they're co-prime.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I checked, in both formulas $a$ and $n$ are indeed coprime. $n$ is a semi-prime, and my problem would be simplified dramatically if I could factor $n$

Answer (score 1):

If you can factor the cubic into the form you give (I assume the $a$ and $b$ in the factored form are different from the $a$ and $b$ in the non-factored form), then you are just trying to find $x$ so that $(ax+b)^3\equiv 0\mod n$.  Trying to solve $y^3\equiv 0\mod n$ first might help then.

If $d$ is very large compared to $n$, you might also want to try reducing $d$ modulo $n$ to a number $d'$ between $0$ and $n-1$, inclusive, before you do anything else.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, $a$ and $b$ are indeed different, and the factored form is $(ax+a^2)^3=C$, where C is the really large number and $a$ is a 2 digit number.

Comment: In this case, then, you could try solving $y^3\equiv C\mod n$ first.  The number $C$ in this case is called a _cubic residue_.  Beyond brute force (which sounds like it might be unfeasible in this case), I don't know any methods of determining whether or not $C$ is a cubic residue offhand.

Comment: Well I am sure that it is a cubic residue because if it is not then the problem I was given would be impossible, so simply due to the fact that it was given I can assume it is possible.

Comment: Ah, good point! 

Something else to think about: if $C$ is a cubic residue modulo $n$, then so is $-C$, and conversely (for much the same reason that if $s$ is an integer cube, then so is $-s$, and conversely), and if we know the cube root of one of $C$ or $-C$, then we can easily find the cube root of the other.

Comment: I tried to compute the cube root of $C$, and it ended up being irrational. Some value of $C+n$ must be a perfect cube, however.

Comment: I meant the cube root of $C$ modulo $n$, i.e. an integer $y$ such that $y^3\equiv C\mod n$.  If we know such an integer, then we can also easily find an integer $z$ such that $z^3\equiv -C\mod n$, and if we know $z$, then we can easily find $y$.  This might help if $n-C (\equiv -C\mod n)$ is small.  For your second sentence, can we say just $C+n$ must be a perfect cube? The definition of $y^3\equiv C\mod n$ means $y^3=kn+C$ for some integer $k.$

Comment: One last comment: this paper might help.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965902000319

Comment: If so, how would one go about finding the integer solution to $y^3 \equiv C\pmod n$? Is that limited to simply iterating through all values of $k$ until a perfect cube is hit, or is it possible to algebraically solve? I'm not sure if I would call $n-C$ small in my instance, that value is a few hundred digits.